# Работа с GUI из основного потока и отдельной Task?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, mvvm

Проблема взаимодействия с GUI при наличии нескольких Task.

В программе есть две Task:
1. Читает данные из системы и заносит их в массив.
2. Выполняет расшифровку данных и обновляет GUI:

Вот сам метод, который вызывает SetSystemValue:

```
    private void Decod(CancellationTokenSource cts)
    {
        if (system_stack != null && system_stack.Length == SignalTable.Count)
        {
            while (!cts.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < system_stack.Length; i++)
                {
                    SignalTable.Signals[i].SetSystemValue(system_stack[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Метод SetSystemValue вызывает в свою очередь одноименный метод из класса Format (в этом классе хранятся модели, которые связаны с вью моделями)(пример расшифровки одного из форматов, в котором вызывается одноименный метод класса Property):

```
case BITFIELD8A:
                    if (_properties != null && _properties.Length == 8)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < _properties.Length; i++)
                        {
                            if ((value & MAIN_MASK[i]) != 0)
                                _properties[i].SetSystemValue(true);
                            else
                                _properties[i].SetSystemValue(false);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
```

Для полноты картины, приведу основную логику класса Property

```
#region events

    public event Action<int, object> UserChange;
    public event Action<object> SystemChange;

    #endregion

    #region methods

    public void SetUserValue(object value)
    {
        UserChange?.Invoke(Index, value);
    }

    public virtual void SetSystemValue(object value)
    {
        SystemChange?.Invoke(value);
    }

    #endregion
```

От класса Property наследуются несколько классов, например BoolProperty.
Вот вью модель, которая отвечает за связь вью и модели:

```
#region constructors

    public BoolPropertyVM(BoolProperty boolProperty) : base(boolProperty.Name)
    {
        _boolProperty = boolProperty;
        _boolProperty.SystemChange += SetSystemValue;
    }

    #endregion

    #region properties

    public bool Value
    {
        get => _value;
        set
        {
            lock (lock_value)
            {
                _value = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Value));
            }
            _boolProperty.SetUserValue(value);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region methods

    private void SetSystemValue(object value)
    {
        if (_value != (bool)value)
        {
            _value = (bool)value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Value));
        }
    }

    #endregion
```

При необходимости дополню вопрос...

Comment: WinForms или WPF?

Comment: @Vasek WPF, .Net 4.0

Comment: У вас что то не работает? Какие то исключения вываливаются? Или в чем, собственно, проблема?

Comment: @tym32167 нет, ошибки не выпадают. По всей видимости, я не правильно вызываю событие, которое обрабатывается в вью модели и обновляет данные.

Comment: А я не пойму, вы пытаетесь что ли из кода изменить CheckBox? Если так, то в WPF для этого реализуют привязки, код вообще об интерфейсе знать не должен. А если не так, то показывайте что и как вы пытаетесь изменить...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ добавил куски кода.

Comment: То есть вся ваша проблема в том, что при вызове `SetSystemValue` у вас `CheckBox` получает галку и потом она пропадает?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ нет, скорей всего, проблема в том, что task не дает установить галочку кликом мышки мне, из кода они появляются. Но когда я ставлю, то она быстро появляется и сразу исчезает...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ как я понимаю, мне нужно выполнять эти события асинхронно? или установиль lock ? или как?

Comment: А вы можете составить [минимальный самодостаточный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Я без него вам вряд ли чем помогу...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76244/discussion-between-uporotayapanda-and-evgeniyz).

Answer (score 0):

**Вариант 1**

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        Thread.Sleep(5000); // эмитация бурной деятельности
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => {
            this.Title = "Готово";
        }));
    });
}
```

**Вариант 2**

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        Thread.Sleep(5000); // эмитация бурной деятельности
    })
    .ContinueWith(
        t => {
            Title = "Готово";
        },
        CancellationToken.None,
        TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion,
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
    );
}
```

Comment: А реализация этого должна быть где? В модели? Или в вью модели?

Comment: @В .net 4.0 такое не подходит...

Comment: @UporotayaPanda код исправил. ну а насчет моделей, то это вам решать как лучше в вашем конкретном случае